# Обнуление массива за константное время

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

На интервью задали такую задачу: дан массив длиной n, необходимо реализовать методы добавления элемента и обнуление(значения всех элементов сбрасывается на 0) массива за константное время. Важное уточнение: использовать тот же массив, без создания нового. 
Варианты, вроде int[] array = new int[]; не подходят.

Возник вопрос с методом обнуления, не могу понять как реализовать. Есть вот такой способ, с использованием дополнительных массивов: http://efesx.com/2009/11/05/reset-an-array-in-constant-time/ но не могу понять логику решения.

Comment: Не, в статье - это метод на грани фола... Он не обнуляется физически, просто объявляется обнуленным, только и всего. Цена - повышенная сложность (и время) обращения к элементам массива...

Comment: Да, но как обнулить? Где то слышал о использовании второго массива и хранении переменной generation с увеличением после каждого добавления элемента. Но не могу найти, только это нашел

Answer (score 0):

**Вставка/удаление**

Массив в котором вставка и удаление делаются за константное время это связанный список, то есть список в каждом элементе которого есть ссылка на следующий и/или предыдущий элемент. Обычно реализуется в виде [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Операция вставки в нем это всего лишь переписывание ссылки на следующий элемент, соответственно это не зависит от размера. Удаление аналогично.

**Операция обнуления.**

Ну как вариант можно завести булевскую переменную, типа `boolean isZero`, если он становится `true`, то любая операция получения значения должна возвращать `0` - надо всего лишь переписать метод получения значения элемента `get()`

Comment: Наверное имеется в виду обнуление с возможностью снова записывать значения. С одним булом если поменять элемент в обнулённом массиве (и сделать `isZero = false`), то все старые значения снова вернуться, либо просто всё время будет нули возвращать

Comment: Ну а что мешает при вставке/удалении или записи нового значения в какой-либо элемент выставить `isZero=false`?

Comment: Ну вот есть массив 3 элемента { 1, 2, 3}. Дальше вызываем метод reset, который устанавливает isZero=true, get(0), get(1), get(2), теперь возвращает нули, дальше делам set(0, num), где выполняется isZero=false, теперь get(1) и get(2) снова возвращают 2 и 3, а должны 0

Comment: А если это именно массив, не связной список? На операции вставки и удаления интервьюеру было всё равно, больше интересовало метод обнуления. И использовать он предлагал именно массив. Как в стандартном массиве использовать прием с boolean переменной?